# Docker container run behavior different on ubuntu server

Tags: docker

I am not sure how to debug container start process.

- I created a templated Blazor wasm hosted  app (.NET 6) in VS 2022 and added docker support. Docker file configuration is default - I did not change anything in it
- I have pushed this image to docker hub.
- I have cleared all the images and containers from cache, docker images -a and docker ps -a return no data.
- I execute docker pull  on both developmen computer (Win11) and ubuntu server.
- I run the container on both Win11 and ubuntu: docker run -dit -p 5000:80 username/imagename

1. On Win11 container is running in the background, status: UP and I can access my app on localhost:5000
2. However, on ubuntu container runs and exists (status: Exited (0) About 3 secs ago).

   - docker logs containername returns no data
   - docker inspect returns in config section: "Architecture": "amd64", "Os": "linux",  "Entrypoint": [ "dotnet", "App.Server.dll" ] - so that looks OK

Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["TestApp/Server/TestApp.Server.csproj", "TestApp/Server/"]
COPY ["TestApp/Shared/TestApp.Shared.csproj", "TestApp/Shared/"]
COPY ["TestApp/Client/TestApp.Client.csproj", "TestApp/Client/"]
RUN dotnet restore "TestApp/Server/TestApp.Server.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/TestApp/Server"
RUN dotnet build "TestApp.Server.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "TestApp.Server.csproj" -c Release -o 
/app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "TestApp.Server.dll"]
```

Any ideas why I have different behavior on ubuntu server, and how can I debug this?

Comment: @Jeppe I already wrote that docker logs is empty, If you mean some other output, can you please specify how to get it?

Comment: Can you check if something is already running on port 80 (e.g. `lsof -i :80`), or try mapping to another port? 80 usually requires sudo. If you change `ENTRYPOINT` in the last line, to `CMD`, you should be able to start the container with e.g. `/bin/bash` (`docker run -it username/imagename /bin/bash`). Then you can manually execute dotnet on your dll and inspect if it starts correctly.